# YAML pipeline error - unable to find folder that Git auto-combines with subfolder

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have a Git repository that I'm using via Azure DevOps, to which I copied a hierarchy of folders and files. Some of these folders only contain another folder. For example:

> content
>
> - epm
>
>   - bin (this contains files)
>   - xin (this contains files)
> - edc
>
>   - bin (this contains files)

What Git is automatically doing is combining the `edc` and `bin` folders into `edc\bin` in the files tree. I even tried manually creating the `edc` folder with a placeholder file, then the `bin` folder under that with a placeholder file, then deleting the placeholder file under `edc`... As soon as I did that, it combined `edc` and `bin` back into `edc\bin`.

The problem with this is that this seems to be an issue when building this via a YAML pipeline into a NuGet package. I use a powershell script that generates the `.nuspec` file and adds the content to be included. This works fine, where it specifies each separate folder and each file within those folders. So one of the entries it adds is `...content\edc`. But then in the NuGet Pack step, which packs the `.nuspec`, it fails, with the error that it cannot find `...content\edc`. Just because of the fact that in the repo's file tree, there is no `...content\edc` - only `...content\edc\bin`.

Is there a way to stop the auto-combining of folders that only contain one folder like that? If not, where can I submit an issue/request for this to be changed?

I do not want to try changing the folder structure or adding extra things, because these are files that are already used in various projects of ours and I'm turning it into a Git repo and NuGet package for better management and don't want to break existing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my issue was that the .nuspec file shouldn't be including folders in the "files" section.  I added checking for the file extension, and if it's blank don't add it to the list.

And I managed to add setting the 'target' as in the same file structure as it is in the repo.  Here is the powershell script for creating the .nuspec file that includes doing both of those, in case anyone else finds this helpful:

```
Param(
[string]$pkgName,
[string]$pkgVersion,
[string]$basePath,
[string]$branchForPackageName,
[string]$contentFolder
)
if($pkgVersion -match '([0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{1,})\.{0,1}([0-9]{0,})$'){
    $matchedVersion = $Matches[0]
    $version=$matchedVersion
    $a=$version.Split(".")
    $version="{0:00}" -f ([int]$a[0]) + "." + "{0:00}" -f ([int]$a[1]) + "." + "{0:00}" -f ([int]$a[2]) + "." + "{0:00}" -f ([int]$a[3])

    $files=Get-ChildItem -Path $basePath\$contentFolder -Recurse
    Write-Host $files.Count " items in " $basePath\$contentFolder
    $baseName=$pkgName+".nuspec"
    $nuspecFile = Join-Path $basePath $baseName
    if((Test-Path $nuspecFile)){
        Remove-Item $nuspecFile
    }
    $title = $pkgName+"."+$branchForPackageName
    $description = (Get-Content -Path $basePath\$contentFolder\README.md)[1]
    if($description -eq ""){
        $description = $title+" Support DLL"
    }
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "<package >"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "  <metadata>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <id>$title</id>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <version>$version</version>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <title>$title</title>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <authors>me</authors>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <owners>me</owners>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <description>$description</description>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <copyright>Copyright 2021</copyright>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <tags>$pkgName</tags>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "  </metadata>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "  <files>"
    for($n=0; $n -lt $files.Count; $n++){
        $fileName = $files[$n].FullName
        if(([IO.Path]::GetExtension($fileName) -ne "")){
            $fileName -match "\\$contentFolder\\(?<remainder>.*)"
            $targetFile = $matches['remainder']
            Add-Content $nuspecFile "    <file src=""$fileName"" target=""content\$pkgName\$targetFile"" />"
        }
    }
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "  </files>"
    Add-Content $nuspecFile "</package>"
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not combining the folders, it's just visually telling you that there are no files directly in "edc". This is entirely an aesthetic choice by Microsoft (btw, Github does this as well). You can use any Git client to inspect the file system and it will be normal.

There doesn't look to be any way to disable this feature.

Comment: Yeah, and I can actually get to the "edc" folder itself if in the URL I remove "%2Fbin".  But I need the pipeline to be able to find ..."content\edc".

Comment: The edc folder is still there. As long as you have _something_ inside it will remain. Be aware that Git doesn't store folders - just files. So if you have a folder with no files or sub-files within, the folder essentially doesn't exist.